# Git remote url is ok but push impossible because url is different

Tags: git, url, repository, push

I'm facing a strange issue with git.
To explain in a simple way, i've just clone a git repository, make some changes, add, commit and push. All ok except the push command.

```
git push -u origin master
fatal: http://myusername@www.mygit.com/pathto/cv.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

Why i've got that /info/refs on my url??
When i check i don't have that.

```
git remote -v
origin  http://myusername@www.mygit.com/pathto/cv.git (fetch)
origin  http://myusername@www.mygit.com/pathto/cv.git (push)
```

or

```
git config -l | grep remote.origin.url
remote.origin.url=http://myusername@www.mygit.com/pathto/cv.git
```

Thanks in adavance for your future answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few researches, it seems it's a bug with git-usercontent-plugin on my Ubuntu 16.04, when cloning through http to a newer version of git, it reported info/refs not valid.
For now, the only workaround i've found is to clone and then push by SSH

```
git clone ssh://git@www.mygit.com:[PortNumberIfIs]/pathto/cv.git
```